# PHP using xpath output

Tags: php, xpath

I just started playing with xpath and need some help.

I'm using tvdb's api and have the following xml (shortened for the question)

```
<Data>
   <Episode>
      <id>4762752</id>
      <EpisodeName>I.</EpisodeName>
      <EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber>
      <SeasonNumber>1</SeasonNumber>
   </Episode>
   <Episode>
      <id>4762756</id>
      <EpisodeName>II.</EpisodeName>
      <EpisodeNumber>2</EpisodeNumber>
      <SeasonNumber>1</SeasonNumber>
   </Episode>
</Data>
```

I want to get all the Episode details where episode number = something and season number is equal to something.

I think I have the xpath query correct but I cannot (or do not know how to) access the data after.

My code so far:

```
$tvdbSeriesData = simplexml_load_file($tvdbSeriesFeed);

$tvdbEpisodes = $tvdbSeriesData->xpath("//Data/Episode[SeasonNumber/text() = '$seasonNumber'][EpisodeNumber/text() = '$episodeNumber']");

echo $tvdbEpisodes->id;
```

This is my first try with xpath, so apologies if this is trivial, but could someone throw me in the right direction or explain to me what I've done wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: It's look like working fine if you try print_r($tvdbEpisodes);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xpath` function returns `Array` with the results of your xpath query:

```
$tvdbSeriesFeed = '<Data>
   <Episode>
      <id>4762752</id>
      <EpisodeName>I.</EpisodeName>
      <EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber>
      <SeasonNumber>1</SeasonNumber>
   </Episode>
   <Episode>
      <id>4762756</id>
      <EpisodeName>II.</EpisodeName>
      <EpisodeNumber>2</EpisodeNumber>
      <SeasonNumber>1</SeasonNumber>
   </Episode>
</Data>';

$tvdbSeriesData = simplexml_load_string($tvdbSeriesFeed);
$seasonNumber = 1;
$episodeNumber = 1;
$tvdbEpisodes = $tvdbSeriesData->xpath("//Data/Episode[SeasonNumber/text() = '$seasonNumber'][EpisodeNumber/text() = '$episodeNumber']");

echo $tvdbEpisodes[0]->id; // 4762752
```

> I used the function `simplexml_load_string` only for the example to work.

You can also var_dump the results:

```
var_dump($tvdbEpisodes);
```

Will output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#3 (4) {
    public $id =>
    string(7) "4762752"
    public $EpisodeName =>
    string(2) "I."
    public $EpisodeNumber =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $SeasonNumber =>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```